# Installer crashes installing qt and qt creator on ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, installation, qt-creator

I'm attempting to install Qt 5.11.2 and Qt creator through the .run installer found on their website.

I can get through the installer just fine, but when the installer finishes downloading and starts installing to my filesystem it always hangs at the exact same point.

Specifically, when its writing /Qt5.11.2/Src/qtwebengine portions. However I don't believe this is the issue because even if I uncheck the box for web engine before installing it still crashes at a specific point somewhere else. Ubuntu gives me the option to force close every time, I have waited to make sure it doesn't come back but it never does.

Can anyone offer any help? I'm not sure if maybe i'm missing some dependencies the installer needs or there's just something wrong with Qt's installer?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you just tried waiting for a few minutes? I do not think it actually crashes. It just hangs the GUI, but is still working in the background. Happens to me as well on one of my systems. Just wait 10-20 minutes and see what happens

Comment: @Felix thanks you were right, guess i'm not patient enough. I left it going for about 20 minutes and it ran the rest of the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to let it sit for 20 minutes.